# Javascript : innerHTML.replace use URL

Tags: javascript, url, replace

this ori html code

```
<td>Name: <b>ozawa</b><br />Country: <b>Japan</b></td>
<td>Name: <b>alexas</b><br />Country: <b>USA</b></td>
```

my js code

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('<Name: <b>', 'g'),'Name: <a href="http://www.example.com/user/')
                                                 .replace(new RegExp('<\/b><br>Country:', 'g'),'" target="_blank" ><b>???????<\/b><\/a><br>Country:');
```

output from my js

```
<td>Name: <a href="http://www.example.com/user/ozawa" target="_blank" ><b>???????</b></a><br />Country: <b>Japan</b></td>
<td>Name: <a href="http://www.example.com/user/alexas" target="_blank" ><b>???????</b></a><br />Country: <b>USA</b></td>
```

how change ??????? to name ozawa and alexas use js,
any idea ?

i want ouput

```
<td>Name: <a href="http://www.example.com/user/ozawa" target="_blank" ><b>ozawa</b></a><br />Country: <b>Japan</b></td>
<td>Name: <a href="http://www.example.com/user/alexas" target="_blank" ><b>alexas</b></a><br />Country: <b>USA</b></td>
```

Thanks for everybody who can help me :D

Comment: `output from my js` is that output from your js code?

Comment: and why you place `???????` there?

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('<Name: <b>', 'g'),'Name: <a href="http://www.example.com/user/')
                                                 .replace(new RegExp('<\/b><br>Country:', 'g'),'" target="_blank" ><b>???????<\/b><\/a><br>Country:');` replace by `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('<Name: <b>', 'g'),'Name: <a href="http://www.example.com/user/')
                                                 .replace(new RegExp('<\/b><br>Country:', 'g'),'" target="_blank" ><b>ozawa<\/b><\/a><br>Country:');`

Comment: now i'm edit again to 1st code, code error after change. now use 2 lines.

Comment: what error you are getting/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a million times easier done with PHP. Anyway,

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML
.replace(new RegExp('<td>Name: <b>(.*?)<\/b>', 'g'),
'<td>Name: <a href="http://www.example.com/user/$1" target="_blank"><b>$1</b></a>');
```

You should seriosuly consider removing those `<b>` tags and using css instead.

Comment: @jamesbond I had a slight mistake in the regex, `?` was placed outside `(.*)`. I edited the answer and it is correct now. Good luck! `:)`

Comment: Gud one +1 from my side